# how to report exponentiated coefs of a coxph model with stargazer

Tags: r, stargazer, cox-regression

Suppose I have `cox.model`

```
cox.model <- coxph(Surv(stop, event) ~ (rx + size + number) * strata(enum),
      cluster = id, bladder1)
```

I want to create a model report table which contains `exp(coefs)` instead of `coeficients`

```
stargazer(cox.model)
```

is there a parameter like `exponentiate = TRUE` which would report `exp(coefs)` instead of `coefs`?, or I need to transform the model results before passing to `stargazer()`?